# Docker - getting disk quota exceeded while pulling image

Tags: docker, openvz

I am running docker on OpenVZ container on CentOS 7, it is up and running but I am getting issue while I try to run `docker run -it ubuntu bash`  .

While `docker run -it hello-world` and `docker run -it busybox` was successful.

I am getting the below issue:

```
[root@vps dir]# docker run -it ubuntu bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from ubuntu
83e4dde6b9cf: Extracting [===================>                               ] 26.18 MB/65.79 MB
83e4dde6b9cf: Error downloading dependent layers
29460ac93442: Download complete
d2a0ecffe6fa: Download complete
d2a0ecffe6fa: Error pulling image (latest) from ubuntu, ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: open /usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/auto/PerlIO/scalar/scalar.bs: Error pulling image (latest) from ubuntu, ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: open /usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/auto/PerlIO/scalar/scalar.bs: disk quota exceeded
```

`docker.service` file is set as below ::

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -s vfs -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

**Docker Details:**

```
[root@vps dir]# docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

**OS Details:**

```
[root@vps dir]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
[root@vps dir]# uname -a
Linux vps.server.com 2.6.32-042stab108.5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 17 20:20:17 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Disk Details:**

```
[root@vps ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       40G  2.4G   38G   6% /
devtmpfs        1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.0G  144K  1.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Comment: Finally, the issue was fixed by my VPS provider staff with the comments as `the issue originates with the amount of inodes allocated to the VPS, the VPS reinstall/build script allocated very few inodes vs what's really needed, I've corrected this now`. I was not sure where to add this info so added comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For marking answer, copying the comment and updating here. was not having access to post answer in year 2015.

Finally, the issue was fixed by my VPS provider staff with the comments as `the issue originates with the amount of inodes allocated to the VPS, the VPS reinstall/build script allocated very few inodes vs what's really needed, I've corrected this now.` I was not sure where to add this info so added comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your disk space (allocated in this OpenVZ container) is full?

If that is the case, delete all dangling images:

```
alias drmiad='docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)'
drmiad
```

Comment: I tried this command and after that I was able to pull centos image properly but again when I tried to pull ubuntu image, got same error again. Is there any way to turn off disk quota for docker as I have enough space. I have added the disk details.